# Pandas 0.13.1 use of groupby( ) with drop_duplicates( ) or dropna ( )

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I've just updated from a previous version to Pandas 0.13.1 - happily, this has opened up some options to me. Unhappily, it appears to have caused problems for some of my data wrangling code. I hadn't made any changes other than updating the Pandas version from 0.11.0

The code that worked before, and no longer works, is as follows:

```
g_pres = g_pres.groupby(['follow','Focal','std_epoch']).dropna(0)
```

and/or

```
g_pres = g_pres.groupby(['follow','Focal','std_epoch']).drop_duplicates(0)
```

Using either results in the following Attribute Error:

```
 ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-169-5d3c7458da40> in <module>()
 ----> 1 g_pres = g_pres.groupby(['follow','Focal','std_epoch']).dropna(0)

 //anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.pyc in __getattr__(self, attr)
     293 
     294         if hasattr(self.obj, attr) and attr != '_cache':
     --> 295             return self._make_wrapper(attr)
     296 
     297         raise AttributeError("%r object has no attribute %r" %

//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.pyc in _make_wrapper(self, name)
    308                    "using the 'apply' method".format(kind, name,
    309                                                      type(self).__name__))
--> 310             raise AttributeError(msg)
    311 
    312         f = getattr(self.obj, name)

AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'dropna' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects,         try using the 'apply' method
```

I have looked at the release notes, searching for groupby, drop_duplicates, and drop_na, but I can't find anything to indicate (at least to me) what might have caused this change. I am a beginner so perhaps I'm overlooking something.

Does the drop_duplicates function no longer work for groupby dataframes? Is there a new syntax? ...Is this a feature or a bug?

I thought perhaps the addition of the inplace method meant I needed to specify something that had been the default previously, but a look at the documentation for the relevant methods didn't yield any progress.

[EDITED TO ADD EXAMPLE DATA]

Example input:

```
      follow     std_epoch     Focal     0
 0    1          1             53704     51602
 1    1          1             53704     51602
 2    1          2             53704     51602
 3    2          1             53505     51509     
 4    2          2             53505     51509
```

Example output, where I want to group by follow, std_epoch, and Focal -- and drop duplicate values from column '0', group-wise (in this example, that's row 2 in the input).

```
      follow     std_epoch     Focal     0
 0    1          1             53704     51602
 1    1          2             53704     51602
 2    2          1             53505     51509     
 3    2          2             53505     51509
```

Comment: woops - thanks for the edit, @EdChum

Comment: you can't dropna on a group; doesn't make sense, this is just a list of groups; are you trying to **filter** ? what are you trying to do? give a small example of input and outpu

Comment: I'm trying to drop NaN and duplicates, group-wise. '0' is the name of a column. I've added input and output, above.

Comment: @Jeff I just realized that while I want to use groupby and drop_duplicates(), I don't need to do so at the same time. I can just drop duplicates first across the whole dataframe, then use groupby. Still not sure why this worked in the previous version but creates an error in pandas 0.13.1 - but for all practical purposes I guess I've answered my own question thanks to your comment.

Comment: gr8! by definition if you ``groupby`` on the duplicated columns the group that is generated doesn't have duplicates!

Comment: 0.13.1 got a lot more strict about just doing any old method on a ``DataFrameGroupBy`` object (which is what ``g=df.groupby(...)`` is. to prevent odd error messages.

Comment: the only thing worse than an error message is an error without a message, so I'm appreciative of this kind of change. despite confusion.

Comment: haha....you are right! ironically we just had a whole discussion about beefing up the docs for groupby: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6944

Comment: @M.A.Kline There was a small line about this in the release notes of 0.13 (`Begin removing methods that don’t make sense on GroupBy objects (GH4887)`), but I think it is normal that you didn't find that one ... :-). So the reason this did work previously is that just all methods that are available for dataframes, were also available for GroupBy objects, while now only the ones that are listed explicitly in a whitelist (the ones that make sense)

Comment: @joris thanks for the clarification. I had wondered whether that applied to this method...

Answer (score 0):

Solution: basically, to rethink the problem. As noted in my comment, I don't need to use groupby to drop duplicates, I'd just put them in the same line in my previous code. I'm still not clear on why this creates an error where it didn't before (perhaps it should always have thrown an error, though it did produce the outcome I was looking for!). However, I'm simply doing this in two lines of code now.

To drop duplicates:

```
 df = df.drop_duplicates()
```

To create grouped object:

```
df = df.groupby(['column1','column2'])
```

Comment: I just had a similar problem and solved it with `df.groupby('my_column').apply(pd.Series.dropna)`. But the versions are differents since I join the party late :-)

Answer (score 0):

In order to apply a method on a DataFrame that is grouped; your need to use a loop as follows:

```
display = IPython.display.display

g_pres = g_pres.groupby(['follow','Focal','std_epoch'])

for a,b in g_pres:
    z = b.dropna(0)
    display(z)
```